# Retrofit2 авторизация

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Есть такой `HTTP` клиент:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static MessengerApi service;
    private static OkHttpClient client;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(MessengerApi.class);
    }
}
```

И такой интерфейс:

```
public interface MessengerApi {
    @GET("users")
    Observable<User> users();
}
```

Мне нужно теперь еще добавить авторизацию (username, password). Как это сделать? 
Немного запуталась в тьюториалах.

API:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотря какой у вас api. авторизация обычно происходит через POST запрос. Если вы нам покажете описание функции, то будет гораздо проще помочь вам

Comment: @miha_dev добавила

Answer (score 4, accepted):

во первых какая у вас используется авторизация?

если basic, тогда используйте, как пример

```
"Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

и

```
@GET("users")
Observable<User> users(@Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

Comment: А как понять используется basic авторизация или не basic? Вот эта строчка ""Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP)" - это String auth? Куда ее нужно добавить?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
, a ""Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP)" в auth пихаешь.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте объект для логин/пароля

```
public class RequestLogin {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Потом передайте его как параметр функции сервиса

```
public interface MessengerApi {
    @GET("login")
    Observable<User> login(RequestLogin login);
}
```

И используете так

```
RequestLogin login = new RequestLogin();
login.setUsername("moylogin");
login.getPassword("moy-parol");
call = messengerApi.login(login);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все таки get использовать, то так примерно

```
@GET("users")
Observable<User> users(@Query("username") String username,@Query("password") String password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Тогда ответ лучше обернуть в класс:

```
class UserResponse {
        private List<User> user;
    }

class User {
        private String username;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private int properties;
    }
```

функция Retrofit будет такой

```
@GET("users")
Observable<UserResponse> login(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

Comment: По поводу @Query("username") username -  выдает Annotations are not allowed here,  Cannot resolve symbol "username"

Comment: забыл тип указать. Поправил ответ